# Problem with scheduler.address using Dask (ValueError: cannot get address of non-running Server)

Tags: python, dask, scheduler, distributed-computing, dask-distributed

I would like to run code for distributed computing using Dask.

I have this code for Scheduler PC:

```
# some imports
import ...
import dask.distributed
import socket

# some functions 

def some_function():
  # etc.

def handle_files(file, etc):
  # some code
  return some_output

def find_free_port():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', 0))
    port = s.getsockname()[1]
    s.close()
    return port

def main():
  # some code
  
  list_of_files = ['file_path1', 'file_path2',...]
  scheduler = dask.distributed.Scheduler(protocol='tcp', host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=find_free_port())
  scheduler.start()

  client = dask.distributed.Client(scheduler.address)

  futures = [client.submit(handle_files, file, etc) for file in list_of_files]
  results = client.gather(futures)

  # rest of the code
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have recieved this error:

> File "C:\Users..\file.py",
> line 401, in 
> main()
>
> File "C:\Users..\file.py",
> line 382, in main
> client = dask.distributed.Client(scheduler.address)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 571,
> in address
> raise ValueError("cannot get address of non-running Server")
>
> ValueError: cannot get address of non-running Server

Does anyone know, why it is caused and how to solve it? I have "scheduler.start()", so scheduler should run... Then I have no idea why it does not work.

I am working with Spyder IDE (running from Anaconda, so in some cases I use also conda prompt).

Answer (score 0):

I just gave the `await` and `asyncio` and code work. Schuduler start is asynchornous so scheduler.adrees was execute before server started...with await I made sure that scheduler already started...I put corrected code snipped here for those who have similar problem.

```
await scheduler.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Why are you not using the LocalCluster class instead of starting the Scheduler yourself?

Comment: When I will use LocalCluster then I can still host to make Worker PCs work? LocalCluster  makes worker also from Scheduler PC?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question, could you try to phrase it differently?